# I can't get data from edittext in fragment after I replace fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext, fragment

I have two fragment with edittext, data from first edittext I gets but after I call second fragment I can't get data from edittext in second fragment. The Logcat said me that data from second edittext is void.

**This is a first fragment class**

```
package com.example.n;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FragmentAdd extends Fragment {
    EditText et1;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_add, container, false);
            et1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            return rootView ;
        }

}
```

**This is a second fragment class**

```
    package com.example.n;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class FragmentAdd2 extends Fragment {
    EditText et2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_add2, container, false);
        et2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        return rootView ;
    }

    public String getEditText(){
        /*FragmentAdd2 fragmentAdd3 = new FragmentAdd2();
        String data =  fragmentAdd3.et2.getText().toString();*/
        String data = et2.getText().toString();
        return data;
    }

}
```

**This is a part of main class**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onClick(View view){
    FragmentAdd fragmentAdd = new FragmentAdd(); 
    String data =  fragmentAdd.et1.getText().toString();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onClick(View view){
    FragmentAdd2 fragmentAdd2 = new FragmentAdd2(); 
    String data =  fragmentAdd2.et2.getText().toString();
}

*LogCat*


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: you see Android is not your everyday java, and its annoying. Your editText has not be initialised because the View has not been converted from xml, **WHY because** the you need to let android create your fragment,re-search on fragment transanctions Sir, honeycode,

Comment: I don't uderstand what I must do, my fragment transaction I made in method on Create but I don't show in this page. And why I show my fragment transactions, I succesful replace my fragment to second fragment. But access to my edittext in second fragment I don't get.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of accessing a fragment method from activity is

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.methodName();
```

or

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your Tag");
fragment.methodName();
```

"Your Tag" is the tag that you passed in the parameter when you added or replaced a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentAdd2 fragmentAdd2 = new FragmentAdd2(); //new fragment instance
String data =  fragmentAdd2.et2.getText().toString();
```

The code above points to a different `Fragment`, if you want to get Text from the `Fragment` you need to point to the `Fragment` you added to the Transaction, and that will get rid of the **`NPE`** to get your `Fragment` you can use `Tag` and `FragmentManager`

Suppose when you added the Fragment you use `Transaction.add(int,Fragment,tag)`
you can now call your Fragment with `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag)` after that  since you want your `EditText` you can cast it to your preferred `Fragment` Class .ie. `FragmentAdd2` or `FragmentAdd` then you can retrieve your stuff.

Hope it helps